# What are the options to figure out what exactly the .exe does step by step?

Tags: xml, exe

Background: I have been tasked to figure out minor IT problems with my company. I really have no background in computer programming or CS or really anything other than just figuring out problems I come across with everyday use.

There is an .exe file that is to take the information entered on a Google Sheet, creates the project in Aceproject and adds the location to a map along with creating a .csv file in that folder. I cannot for the life of me find the source code. There are .xml files in the same folder, but to my understanding they only are a type of file both humans and computers can understand. Is it possible for the .exe file basically to only open certain websites and the .xml's structure the information the .exe file gets?

Basically, I am not able to find the source code. The maker of the code is no longer contacting anyone in my company, and no one knows anything about computers to help figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow. I understand you hope to find experts here that can help you out, but it's highly unlikely that anyone here actually can, the question is way too vague for that.

Answer (score 0):

Any attempt to look inside this .exe file to discover what it does requires a very high level of expertise - it's the kind of thing that security specialists do it they have reason to think the code might be malicious. The other possible ways of discovering anything about it are (a) experimental: see what happens when you execute it, look for places it is called from and what parameters are supplied, look to see what happens if you remove the XML files that it (possibly) uses as input data; or (b) historical: find out who created the file, when and why. It looks to me as if you've already been doing that, without success.

A program without its source code is basically useless. If it's performing a useful function and you have no reason to suspect anything malicious, then you can continue to run it in its current state until it stops working (e.g. because of a change of operating system), but if you need to change it in anyway then you are basically hosed: throw it away and start again.

If it's any consolation, I've seen major computer vendors lose the source code of important programs. The programmers generally understand the importance of tracking source code, but unless the senior management also understand it, artefacts like this won't survive a couple of reorganisations.